# Print all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix by DP

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, dynamic

I am unable to "**Print all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix**" by using **Dynamic Programming** .
In mostly site i saw it was done by recursion with give exponential time complexity.
Can any provide me any reference or any link to create a c++ program for this problem......
You can move only right or down in matrix at any step.
As i said i am unable to understand means i am not started any thing in this...
Thanks.

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying this yourself. Also, asking for an online resource is specifically off-topic. Here is help with turning this into an answerable question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The problem description is not clear enough. It assumes that all possible paths are meant which are not longer than the shortest path, doesn't it?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Building and running a HelloWorld? Extending a HelloWorld to take input of m and n? Outputting any path through that matrix? Outputting all paths through a 1x1 matrix? Outputting all paths through a 2x1 matrix? 2 x 2 ? Outputting all paths through a (n+1) x m matrix? Proving that a program is dynamic programming insteaf of only using a recursive function?

Comment: Can you describe where you are stuck? Is this a homework problem? Did you try out anything? The question itself is incomplete - can I move in all 8 directions from a given cell?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have exponential paths, you cannot run from exponential time if you have to **print all of them**. On the other hand, if you just want to **count**, it can be done much faster.

A simple recursive solution to print all paths:

```
print_path(x, y, path){
    if(x == height && y == width) print(path)
    if(x < height) print_path(x + 1, y, path + (x, y))
    if(y < width)  print_path(x, y + 1, path + (x, y))
```

---

If you just want to **count**, you can use DP. Suppose you start at (0,0) and end at (2,2). Begin by noticing that, when in (2,i) or (i,2), you have only one way to get to the (2,2), which is going straight:

```
0 0 1
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

Now, for each 0  element starting from (1,1), the number of paths to the end starting there is the sum of the cell in its right with the cell in its bottom:

```
0 0 1        0 0 1        0 3 1        6 3 1
0 2 1   =>   3 2 1   =>   3 2 1   =>   3 2 1
1 1 1        1 1 1        1 1 1        1 1 1
```

So your answer is 6. As you loop through all cells of the matrix. The complexity is O(n²). Although, you can use the fact that square matrices are always symmetrical and the end value of a NxN matrix will be the [central binomial coefficient of N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient). This can reduce a lot the complexity. For example, if your matrix is 5x7, you can deduce all diagonal of the matrix:

```
0  0 70  0  0  0  0
0  0  0 20  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  6  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  2  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

A path from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix consists so in a permutation of  `m-1` right moves and `n-1` bottom moves.

`std::next_permutation` allows to iterate over permutation

```
std::string path(n - 1, 'B');
path.resize(n - 1 + m - 1, 'R'); // path is sorted and would be {B, .., B, R, .., R}

do {
     std::cout << path << std::endl; // or any other way to print it
} while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/mNqDli)